# La Pseudo clase Hoover no funciona

Tags: html, css, hover

Tengo un problema a la hora de seguir un tutorial para mejorar mi css, pero cuando llego a la parte donde debo colocar la pseudo clase hoover en mis enlaces, no funciona.
Trate de revisar si el codigo HTML y CSS estan bien, y no veo ningun inconveniente a la hora de escribirlo.

Les dejo mi codigo:

El tutorial que sigo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2imkhmhOFo&t=574s&ab_channel=Fazt

```css
/* Navegation */
.nav-menu {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.nav-logo {
    width: 70px;
}

/* Nav Left */
.nav-menu ul {
    display: flex;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}

/* .nav-menu ul li a {
    padding: 20px;
} */

.nav.menu ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}

.nav-menu ul.nav-list {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <nav class="nav-menu">
            <img class="nav-logo" src="src/img/Arg-programa.png" alt="Logo-Pagina">
        
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recetas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Más</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <hr>


    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal escrita la clase

Tu código

```
.nav.menu ul li a:hover
```

Cómo Debería

```
.nav-menu ul li a:hover
```

Comment: Como recordatorio aparte css se guarda en el cache y no siempre carga. Pará eso puedes recargar la página con ctrl + shift + R

Comment: Esta clase de errores, si es este, entonces se cierra la pregunta como error de tipeo...

Answer (score 0):

Sería mejor que aplicaras una `class` para los enlaces de la navbar, porque además de poner el subrayado deberías cambiar otras cosas, como el viñeteado del `li`o el resaltado en azul que aplica por defecto.

Te adjunto como te podría quedar funcionando y visualmente corregido:

```css
.nav-menu {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.nav-logo {
    width: 70px;
}

/* Nav Left */
.nav-menu ul {
    display: flex;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}

/* .nav-menu ul li a {
    padding: 20px;
} */

.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.link-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
}

.link-nav:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}

.nav-menu ul.nav-list {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <nav class="nav-menu">
            <img class="nav-logo" src="src/img/Arg-programa.png" alt="Logo-Pagina">
        
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li><a class="link-nav" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a class="link-nav" href="#">Recetas</a></li>
                <li><a class="link-nav" href="#">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a class="link-nav" href="#">Más</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <hr>


    </div>

</body>
```